# LinkedList : Is there a reason that getFirst() and getLast() are pointing to the same element?

Tags: java, list, collections, linked-list

Are there any cases in which getFirst() and getLast() show the same element when using the LinkedList provided by Collections?

I am parsing data to staging variables to be held; then I am storing these variables in a new object to be stored in my LinkedList using the add() method. However, when I am printing out statements, after every time an object is added to my LinkedList, by using the getFirst() and getLast() they are pointing to the same object?

Please see code below (please dont critic the code too much, I am only a beginner so I know it isn't pretty, but it recreates my problem)

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Parse parse = new Parse();
        parse.main();
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;

public class Parse {
    String[] input = {"1", "a",
        "2", "b",
        "3","c",
        "4", "d"};

    Object tempObject = new Object();

    String tempLength;
    String tempFilename;
    int arrayIndex = 0;
    public static ObjectList objectList = new ObjectList();

    Parse(){
    }

    public void main() {

        for (int i = 0; i != input.length; i++) {
            String stringInput = iterateInputArray(input, i);
            addToTempObject(stringInput);

            Object finalObject = new Object();
            finalObject = tempObject;
            Object tempObject = new Object();

            objectList.addToList(finalObject);

            System.out.println("First:" + ObjectList.listOfObjects.getFirst());
            System.out.println("Last:" + ObjectList.listOfObjects.getLast());
        }
    }

    public String iterateInputArray(String[] input, int arrayIndex){
        String string = input[arrayIndex];
        return string;
    }

    private void addToTempObject(String inputString){
        if (tempLength == null){
            tempLength = inputString;
            tempObject.setLength(inputString);
        }
        else {
            tempObject.setFilename(inputString);
            tempFilename = inputString;
            resetTempVariables();
        }
    }

    private void resetTempVariables() {
        tempLength = null;
        tempFilename = null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Object {

    private String length;
    private String filename;

    public Object( String length, String filename) {

        this.length = length;
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public Object(){
        this.length = null;
        this.filename = null;
    }

    public void setFilename(String filename) {
        this.filename = filename;
    }

    public void setLength(String length) {
        this.length = length;
    }


    public String getLength() {
        return this.length;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return this.filename;
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class ObjectList extends Object {
    public static LinkedList<java.lang.Object> listOfObjects = new
        LinkedList<java.lang.Object>();

    public ObjectList() {
    }

    public void addToList(Object object){
        listOfObjects.add(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: getFirst() and getLast() will be the same if the list contains only 1 element.
Are you sure you add multiple elements to the same list? Or do you accidentaly create a new LinkedList everytime?

Comment: @GreyFairer I could perhaps be creating a new LinkedList every time. But I also ran a print statement with LinkedList.size() and it increases each time an Object is added

Comment: Please provide a [MRE].

Comment: @Turing85 Please see my edited question. Thank you

Comment: Is there anyway you could guide me to which part of the code this is? Sorry if this is too much of a beginner question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced the code. The reduced code is, for the discussion of the prorblem, identical to the provided code:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Scratch {

    public static final Object tempObject = new Object();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {

            list.add(tempObject);

            System.out.printf("First: %s, Last: %s, Size: %d%n",
                list.getFirst(),
                list.getLast(),
                list.size());
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/RP55F5)

The code keeps adding one and the same object (`tempObject`) to the list. Notice the `final` keyword introduced to highlight that variable `tempObject` references the same object over its whole lifetime. Thus, the size of the list grows, but the list contains the same object, over and over again. This is why `getFirst()` and `getLast()` return the same object.

The problem can be fixed by, e.g., moving the declaration of `tempObject` in the loop:

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

class Scratch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i != 10; i++) {
            final Object tempObject = new Object();
            list.add(tempObject);

            System.out.printf("First: %s, Last: %s, Size: %d%n",
                list.getFirst(),
                list.getLast(),
                list.size());
        }
    }
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/5HpGjZ)

Answer (score -1):

yes, a linked list with one element. like following test

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat

class ListSpec extends Specification{

    def "linked list with one elem"(){
        given: "a linked list with one element"
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<>()
        list.add("test")
        expect:"last and first element are same"
        assertThat(list.getFirst()).isEqualTo(list.getLast())
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using Spock, there's no point in using `assertThat`: You simply say `expect: list.first == list.last`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- yes, you're right, but code is better readable with syntax of hamcrest assertThat ... isEqualTo, at least in my opinion

Comment: I mean not syntax of assertj, not hamcrest :(